# Windows permission: Unable to create file despite having permission

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

I have a directory that have the same NTFS permission as another. But I cannot create any file in it while I can in the other one. However, anything else seems to be normal, I can modify existing files, delete files, creating folders and even creating files inside of the newly created folders. But I just can't create any files without administrator's previlege.

I tried most solutions online but I can't fix the permission for this folder. Did anyone have a solution about this?

[image: 1]

The left window shows that I cannot create files within a directory that I have permission to but I can create files inside of its sub-directory which have the same privilige and ownership as its parent. The right window shows that I'm able to create files with Administrator's privilige

[image]

[image]
Effective Access for the current user.

Comment: What folder?   Some folders are system secured.

Comment: @John: In the image : `D:\Microsoft VS Code lnsiders\resources` and `D:\Microsoft VS Code lnsiders\resources\a`.

Comment: @BillSun: In the Advanced Security Settings dialog, click Effective Access and compare the results for the two folders. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Thank you - not readable on my laptop.  That is not a system secured folder. @OP can you reset parent permissions?  Try looking at this Microsoft document.

Comment: This was the document.  I neglected to add it.   https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-reset-file-folder-permissions-to-default-in-windows-10

Comment: Hi @harrymc , Thank you for responding! I checked the effective access of the two folders. I uploaded the results to the original question and they seems to be the same. And it shows that my account does have permission for creating files.

Comment: Hi @John, thank you for responding. It didn't seem to work however I change the permission of the parent directory or copying it to another normal folder.

Comment: There is something significant wrong, so it the suggestions offered did not help, you may need to reset Windows.

Comment: @John yeah, I think it's something with this folder itself. Because it's a external drive, I attached it to another Windows PC and the problem persists. I actually created this folder in macOS with Paragon NTFS drivers. I guess the Paragon driver messed up the permission somehow.

Comment: Try writing to that folder while booting in Safe Mode. This will tell if some startup application is blocking the write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by re-building the directory tree using a simple C++ script below.
https://godbolt.org/z/5MxM1brcc